# Не запускается приложение на версии Android 5 и ниже при установке с Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Не запускается приложение на версии Android 5 и ниже при установке с Android Studio.
При установки билда через Anroid Studio на android 6 и выше версии работает всё хорошо, если android 5 и ниже, то при запуске приложения - крэш. 
Если устанавливать билд собранный вручную (Build->Build APK), то запускается все хорошо на всех версиях Android.

Пробовал:

- Invalidated Cashes /Restart;
- Удалить проект, заново скачать с репозитория;
- Clean project -> Rebuild Project;

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему, если нужна какая-то дополнительная информация, спрашивайте :)

Logs:

```
05-11 13:50:57.873 19062-19062/com.erminesoft.ngc E/System: stat file error, path is /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000012/n/arm64-v8a, exception is android.system.ErrnoException: stat failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-11 13:50:57.918 19062-19062/com.erminesoft.ngc E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
05-11 13:50:58.545 19062-19062/com.erminesoft.ngc E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jivesoftware/smack/tcp/XMPPTCPConnection;
                                                                           at com.erminesoft.ngc.net.XmppManager.<clinit>(XmppManager.java:87)
```

- Версия Android Studio: 2.3.1.
- Gradle: com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1
- Gradle version: 3.3
- compileSdkVersion: 25
- buildToolsVersion: '25.0.2'
- minSdkVersion: 19
- targetSdkVersion: 25

Comment: Не запускается на эмуляторе или на физическом девайсе?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще у вас происходит падение из-за ошибки службы гугл-сервисов `com.google.android.gms` или их просто нет (китайфон, эмулятор без гугл-сервисов) или служба глючит.

Можно попробовать очистить кэши служб гугла и перезапустить их.

[Почитайте здесь, например](http://dadaviz.ru/com-google-android-gms-chto-eto-za-process/)

Comment: дело в том, что на других компах этот же проект билдится на эти же смартфоны и проблем нет